# Strange Issues with IIS and ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, iis

Currently we are debugging some external companies web portal for a product we support, every few hours each day the site 'breaks' the side menu stops functioning properly, I did some comparisons of the HTML when the site is functional and when the site is broken.

When it is broken, the HTML shows that the style sheets are being applied 100s of times.

```
<link href="../../App_Themes/OutlookMenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I suspect this is why the page gets broken, but without any access to the code I am at a dead end, has anyone ever experienced anything like this? I suspect it could be session related or somehow related to the asyncpostback timeout.

Note: after an IISReset everything is normal again for a few hours.

Edit: I did notice in Event Viewer around the time it occurs we get a Warning 1309

with the stack trace containing a load of

```
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
```

Comment: You mean to say that you see that `<link>` element hundreds of times in the HTML of the page?  All in a row?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it appears to me like it is somehow stuck in a loop sending the same data over and over.

Comment: Can you show the rest of that stack trace from that Event Log entry?